# How can I find the number of values in a vector within a certain range of the minimum with R?

Tags: r, sum, range, min

I'm a beginner to R and I'm trying to figure out how to find the number of values +/- 100 of the minimum value in a vector. I've tried:

```
>min(Vector)
>sum(yVec>(min(Vector)-100)>min(Vector))
```

The first code gives me the minimum value in the vector but then I need to find the number of values within 100 of that minimum value.

Comment: Wrap it with `abs`

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by "+/- 100 of the minimum value in a vector". If you have the minimum value of the vector then I would have thought that you would only be searching for the values that are less than the minimum plus 100, right?
Or I don't understand something important here..
Anyway, if I'm not completly off-track you can do something along those lines:
`> v = 1:1000; m <- min(v) + 100; sum(as.logical(lapply(v, function(x) x < m)))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I should have been more clear. I was looking for the number of values within 100 of the minimum so you're right, it would be all values less than the minimum plus 100. I was able to solve it with abcalphabet's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you're trying to find the members of a vector that are within 100 of its minimum. To do so you can just use the `which` function:

```
length(which(Vector < (min(Vector) + 100)))
```

Since the minimum is already the lowest value in your vector you only need to look for the values that are within 100 above your minimum.

[Try it out](http://rextester.com/MHRVRD20059)